# Ruby Endless Loop

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. I have written the code below, its working about 90% except the else statement. The else statement triggers endless loop. I just want it to ask user to try again. Here is my code

```
 puts "Do you want to print something? (Y / N)"
 user = gets.chomp.downcase

 answer = true

 while answer

   if user == "y"
     puts "Something"
     answer = false
   elsif user == "n"
     puts " "
     answer = false
   else
     puts "Invalid input! Please enter Y or N"
   end

end
```

Comment: You never change the value of `user` inside your `while` loop, so it goes on endlessly if the user does not first enter 'y' or 'n'. You need to prompt the user *inside* the loop. In other words, you did a `puts` that says "Invalid input! Please enter Y or N" but you don't request the new input from the user. Just add `user = gets.chomp.downcase` after that for a quick solution.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. I thought since I didn't add  "answer = false". it will remember that condition has not been met and the while loop will automatically prompt user the puts question again. Thanks for the insight

Comment: The program won't prompt the user unless you tell it to prompt the user. It doesn't know what you're thinking. :) The answer posted below shows one way to put that prompting *inside* your loop.

Comment: Thank you. I will remember this in future.

Comment: Btw `while true` can be written as `loop do` what might be a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it (loop do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat shorter (note `user` has gone, the answer is now referred to as `answer`).

```
answer = ""
until (answer  == "y") or (answer == "n")
  puts 'Do you want to print something? (Y/N)'
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase 
end
```

Comment: That is good. The only problem is, I am not getting any output. I wanted to puts "Something" when answer == "y" and nothing when answer == "n"

Comment: One of many variants: `answer = loop do; puts 'Do you want to print something? (Y/N)'; answer = gets.chomp.upcase; break answer if ['Y', 'N'].include?(answer); puts "Please enter 'Y' or 'N'"; sleep(2); end`. (I used `upcase` merely because that's what you asked for.)

Comment: @homer just add `puts "something" if answer=="y"` as last line.

Answer (score 1):

Once you exit the else, `answer` is still true. If you want to re-prompt, you can move your puts and user statement into the loop.

Something like this should work.

```
while true # (alternately) loop do
  puts 'Do you want to print something? (Y/N)'

  case gets.chomp.downcase
  when 'y'
    puts 'foo'
    break
  when 'n'
    puts 'bar'
    break
  else
    puts 'Invalid input! Please enter Y or N'
  end
end
```

You can use `break` to exit out of your loop instead of setting up another variable. Also, this looks like a good use-case for a case statement to have some explicit cases listed.

Comment: Thank you Colton. I like your solution. Much simpler.

Comment: @Homer Anytime - happy coding!

Comment: I would just use `Kernel#loop` and not mention `while true`. `loop` has the advantage that it has a block and therefore keeps that within it away from prying eyes. Also, you might mention that `break` is sometimes used to pass a value outside the loop (e.g. `break my_var`), which, if `loop` is used, is its return value. I use `loop` for virtually all looping.

Comment: @ Cary Swoveland - Thanks for the contribution. Very good suggestion. I'll look into  #loop.